# T-SQL | Counts and ranks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTBL 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    KC1 varchar(10), 
    KC2 varchar(10), 
    KC3 varchar(10), 
    NC1 int, 
    NC2 money, 
    IsON bit
)

INSERT INTO #TempTBL
SELECT 'ABC','MNO','XYZ',1,1.00,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC','MNO','XYZ',1,1.00,0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABD','MNO','XYZ',1,1.10,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABD','MNO','XYZ',1,1.10,0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABD','MNO','XYZ',2,1.00,0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABE','MNO','XYZ',1,1.10,1

SELECT * FROM #TempTBL

DROP TABLE #TempTBL
```

http://ideone.com/HSLynu

I am trying to find unique row number based on KC1, KC2, and KC3 (key columns). Then, I am trying to derive for each unique record, how many records have IsOn = 1 and IsOn = 0. To better understand, below is the output I am expecting. (I am trying to derive RowNum, OnCnt, and offCnt fields).

```
ID  KC1 KC2 KC3 NC1 NC2 IsON    RowNum  OnCnt   OffCnt
1   ABC MNO XYZ 1   1   1       1       1       1
2   ABC MNO XYZ 1   1   0       1       1       1
3   ABD MNO XYZ 1   1.1 1       2       1       2
4   ABD MNO XYZ 1   1.1 0       2       1       2
5   ABD MNO XYZ 2   1   0       2       1       2
6   ABE MNO XYZ 1   1.1 1       3       1       0
```

now before you start saying show your work, let me just say that the part of the tbl I have listed is a portion of a big query I am building. I am just unable to come up with logics for these three things (2 if we consider OnCnt and OffCnt "same").

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RowNum` is actually a `DENSE_RANK()`, and you can use a conditional aggregate for the counts, (either `SUM()` like below, or `COUNT()`):

```
SELECT *
      ,RowNum = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY KC1,KC2,KC3)
      ,OnCNT = SUM(CASE WHEN IsON = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY KC1,KC2,KC3)
      ,OffCNT = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN IsON = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY KC1,KC2,KC3),0)
FROM  #TempTBL
```

Comment: GOALLL!!! thx, this works! Time to figure out implementation. :) thank you Goat CO. Cheers

Comment: Time to investigate the logic. Dense_rank...why no partition by and why order by on key columns? use of COALESCE for OffCNT is to take care of a record where there is no record where IsON = 0? Instead, I am using OffCNT = SUM(CASE WHEN IsON = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY KC1,KC2,KC3)...do you foresee any error(s)?

Comment: The ranking functions rank based on order, ties are awarded the same rank, so if you order by your 3-key fields you'll get a unique number per combination of those fields, partition by would define a group for which to start ranking over again, which would be useful if you wanted to rank players from best to worst for each team, for example.    You're correct about the `COALESCE()`, it's just to return `0` instead of `NULL`. Your `ELSE` will achieve the same without issue.

Comment: Really like your description about Dense_rank..partition by...order by. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Use [Windowing Functions][1]

SELECT *,
 ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY KC1,KC2,KC3) AS Row_Num
 ,COUNT(CASE IsON WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY KC1,KC2,KC3) AS OnCnt
 ,COUNT(CASE IsON WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY KC1,KC2,KC3) AS OffCnt
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Few syntax errors here, extra `ORDER BY` in the `DENSE_RANK()` function, and those `CASE` statements will throw errors in SQL Server (need a `THEN` for each `WHEN`), but right idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response Anon. Yeah, syntex error but idea/logic makes sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

My quick response for this one.

```
SELECT TBL.*,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TBL.KC1,TBL.KC2,TBL.KC3) RowNum, ONCNT, OFFCNT
FROM #TempTBL TBL INNER JOIN 
(SELECT KC1,KC2,KC3,SUM(CAST(IsON AS INT)) ONCNT,COUNT(1) - SUM(CAST(IsON AS INT)) OFFCNT FROM #TempTBL GROUP BY KC1,KC2,KC3) 
CNT ON CNT.KC1 = TBL.KC1 AND CNT.KC2 = TBL.KC2 AND CNT.KC3 = TBL.KC3
```

Comment: Thanks classic_vmk. This also works...a bit complex but does work. Cheers!